# How to set up a heterogeneous multiuser git/svn environment

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I work for a team which uses Subversion as the main VCS but almost everyone has started using git locally via git-svn. Now we are considering switching fully to git.

As an intermediate step, it would be nice to use both of them simultaneously for a while. The problem is not so much the users who are mostly glad to switch to git, it's the continuous integration/build infrastructure we've built around Subversion. Management of course isn't thrilled about any downtime a big bang change would cause, we release new features every two weeks and bug fixes and other minor stuff almost daily. Ideally running these systems in parallel would make the final switch a non-issue.

The problem seems to be that there can be no shared git repository which originates from the Subversion repository. Each parallel git svn merge/rebase creates new git commits which are duplicates. By parallel I mean two developers doing a merge or rebase in their own clones of the same git repository. Even worse, the git svn dcommits seem to change the git commit's ids.

So is this kind of environment even possible, or is git-svn really only meant to be a single-user tool?

Answer (score 5):

First off, I advise against bothering to try to do two central repositories, one svn and one git, certainly not with svn as the core repository.  SVN tends to ignores the hash commit identities of git, so it's not an easy two-way street.

Better to bite the bullet now than have to deal with a mess later.

### SVN Read-Only Mirror

One purpose for svn that I could see being valid, if not amazingly useful for continued svn users, is as a read-only repository.  In other words, you could set up svn to mirror the git repository (at least the master branch), allow checkout, but not allow commits back to svn.  That way if someone wanted to review code or behavior, and was familiar with svn or svn tools, they could make use of that knowledge.  They just wouldn't be in full development mode.

### Ease The Transition to Git

The reasons to stay with svn over git are mainly going to be ones of familiarity, so your best bet may be to A:

Educate with the a basic commandset that would allow someone to translate their most essential behavior from a svn mindset to git usage ( http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html ).  That way they may not be doing the best things that git has to offer, but they'll be able to do the easy basics that require getting git committed.

and B:

Delegate for a while.  While some people are learning git, have them provide patches/branches upstream to a more knowledgable git user to merge in features, & assist them until they're up to speed and comfortable with the tool.

In the end, there's not much getting around the fact that ftp is to svn as svn is to git, to harness the advantages, you need to take the plunge pretty fully.